# how to display image from mysql database in php?

Tags: php

```
<?php 
do {
printf("<section class='sarcina'>
<h1>
<a href='firma.php?id=%s'>%s</a>
</h1>
<div id='image'> <src img='%s' width='100' height='100'> 

<div id='descriere'> 
  <h2>%s lei</h2>
 </div>
</div>
</section>", $pageres["id_sarcini"], $pageres["Den_Comp"],$pageres["foto"], $pageres["suma_ut"]) ;
}
while($pageres=mysql_fetch_array($res));
?>
```

Here I display all the data that i need, all works but I cant display picture. How can I do this in this code?

Comment: Are you storing the image data in your database, or just the location of the image? What does the generated HTML look like?

Comment: Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: First, switch img and src in `<src img='%s' width='100' height='100'>` then post any error messages you are getting.

Comment: How is the image stored in the database? As a filename? Or binary data? Please provide us more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 <img  src='your image url here' width='100' height='100'>
```

instead of

```
 <src img='%s' width='100' height='100'>
```